# How to do a simulation of still water being affected instead of flowing water

Tags: fluid-simulation

Of all the tutorial videos on water simulation, they're all like water flowing from a point and then settling. How would I do it if I want the start of the animation to be an existing body of water. Would I just do a flowing animation, wait until it is still, then just cut the flowing part of the video off?

Comment: Do you need the water to be moving at all? You might not need a simulation. Please explain a bit more what you want to do. Maybe a simple displacement modifier is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Object set to a Flow Behavior of Geometry to convert any part of the mesh that intersects with your domain to liquid particles.  You'd just have to allow a limited amount of time to settle and keyframe the visibility of the object.

[image]

[image]

Particle sims, and particularly this process, seem pretty finicky right now.  I had to go back and change the number of divisions on my domain to sort of "refresh" the sim and update the size and positions of my emitters.  Just a heads up.